# Parameterization of a circle of radius 2 in polar coordinates is not what I would expect

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am trying to represent the circle of radius 2 in polar coordinates.

$$\gamma(t)=(2\cos(t),2\sin(t))$$

where $t\in [0,2\pi]$. The derivative would be

$$\gamma'(t)=-2\sin(t)\partial_x +2\cos(t)\partial_y.$$

Now if we convert the tangent basis vectors to polar coordinates,

$$\partial_x = \cos(t)\partial_r - \frac{1}{r}\sin(t) \partial_\theta.$$

$$\partial_y = \sin(t)\partial_r + \frac{1}{r}\cos(t) \partial_\theta.$$

Then under the substitution, noting that $r=2$, we have

$$\gamma'(t) = -2\sin(t)\partial_x + 2\cos(t) \partial_y\\= -2\sin(t)\left[\cos(t)\partial_r - \frac{1}{2}\sin(t) \partial_\theta\right] + 2\cos(t)\left[\sin(t)\partial_r + \frac{1}{2}\cos(t) \partial_\theta\right]\\=2\partial_\theta.$$

Thus, in polar coordinates, $\gamma'(t) = 2\partial_\theta$.

Now, what I thought is that in polar coordiantes,

$$\gamma_{\text{polar}}(t) = (2, t)$$ where $t\in [0,2\pi]$.

Then we would have $$\gamma'_{\text{polar}}(t)=\partial_\theta.$$

But this does not align with what I found when I started with cartesian coordiantes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $-2\sin(t)\left[\cos(t)\partial_r - \frac{1}{2}\sin(t) \partial_\theta\right] + 2\cos(t)\left[\sin(t)\partial_r + \frac{1}{2}\cos(t) \partial_\theta\right]\\=\dfrac{1}{2}(2\sin^2(t)+2\cos^2(t))\partial_\theta=\partial_\theta$

Comment: The point is that $\partial_\theta$ is *not* a unit vector. Its length depends on the point $(r,\theta)$ you're at. And although $\partial_r$ has constant length, it varies according to the point you're at, too.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah I see so the dependence on $r$ is encoded in the definition of the vector?

Comment: Where did your equations for $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ in terms of $\partial_r$ and $\partial_\theta$ come from?